# I can't authorized in Azure using Python code

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, unauthorized

I am trying to authorize in Azure using below Python code:

```
from os import environ as env
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

import json

with open(r'C:Project\cred.json') as data_file:
data = json.load(data_file)


subscription_id = data["subscription_id"]
TENANT_ID = data["tenant_id"]
CLIENT_ID = data["client_id"]
CLIENT_SECRET = data["client_secret"]

KEYVAULT_NAME = env.get("myapp")
KEYVAULT_URI = f"https://{KEYVAULT_NAME}.scm.azurewebsites.net"

_credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=TENANT_ID,
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET
)

_sc = SecretClient(vault_url=KEYVAULT_URI, credential=_credentials)
DEMO_DB_USERNAME = _sc.get_secret("DemoUserName").value
DEMO_DB_PASSWORD = _sc.get_secret("DemoUserPassword").value
```

But I am getting error:

> azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: Operation returned an invalid status 'Unauthorized'

Kindly help me to understand where I am wrong. I think I have mistake in importing environ. Maybe it is not needed and there are any other ways to connect to Azure and my own account. The main goal is to reach to web application which is protected by Azure login/password credentials. And the target is to pass authorization by using secret_id/client_id/tenant_id NOT login and password. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you haven't done this already, can you try to simplify all this to a point where it works and you don't have all this abstraction around you (loading from json, using env, etc).

So: Just manually type in all the things first as strings to see if that works. You can also print the variables coming in to confirm they have the value that you expect.

When you get to a point where that works, then add back in the abstraction (loading from the file etc.).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am trying do it, but my main problem is I can't fully understand how I can connect to my Azure Portal account. If I will find the simple way I will use it to connect. But for now it is not possible even without the abstraction. Can you help me and give me some hints? I think I am missing something global

Comment: Hi Jay. Have you checked this link? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/authorization?view=azure-python

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate with Azure with python make sure that you have registered am application in Azure AD and provided the details as above.

*And then you installed the package called*;

```
pip install azure-identity
```

For example after installing you can use `DefaultAzureCredential` in your application;

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

# Acquire a credential object
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(
        account_url="https://<my_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net",
        credential=credential)
```

For more information please refer the below links:-

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**|[***Configure authentication in a sample Python web app by using Azure AD B2C***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-python-web-app?tabs=windows) & [***Walkthrough: Integrated authentication for Python apps with Azure services***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/walkthrough-tutorial-authentication-01)